# Angular Form custom validator http observable returning null on http call

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms, angular-observable

I am trying to setup a form field which will check if a email exists. I have looked at a few examples and have got the validation working, but when I implement the http pipe, map to my services' Observable, it throws it as null? I can assume I am piping to it incorrectly from my service but I am not too sure.

Is anyone able to help me?

`core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailService' of undefined`

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  signUpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private emailService: EmailService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required], [this.validateEmailNotTaken]]
    });
  }

  //Validator for checking if email name is taken or not
  validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> {

      if (control.value === null || control.value.length === 0) {
        return of(null);
      }
      else {
        return timer(1000).pipe(
          switchMap(() => {


            this.emailService.checkEmailExists(control.value).pipe(
              map(res => {
                //Do what with response
                console.log(res);

                if (!res) {
                  return { taken: true };
                }

                return of(null);
              })
            );


          })
        );
      }


  }

}
```

**email.service.ts**

```
 interface IServerCheckEmailExists {
    "available": boolean;
}
export interface ICheckEmailExists {
    taken: boolean;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EmailService {

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    }

    checkEmailExists(email: string): Observable<ICheckEmailExists[]> {

        var postObject = {"action": "checkEmailExists"};
        return this._http.post<IServerCheckEmailExists[]>("myapiurl/" + email, postObject).pipe(
            map(o => o.map((sp): ICheckEmailExists => ({
                taken: sp.available
            })))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: did you correctly import emailservice to appcomponent ?

Comment: To reproduce the issue, a stackblitz will be needed.

Comment: Yes I left the imports out of the sample code but I have `import { EmailService } from '../_services';`

Comment: Am I correctly accessing the `emailService.checkEmailExists()` within the `pipe(switchMap()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue that I see in your code is that you're not returning the call to `this.emailService.checkEmailExists(control.value)` inside the `switchMap` which you should be doing since you are using `{}`. Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  AbstractControl
} from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable, of, timer } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, map } from "rxjs/operators";

import { EmailService } from "./email.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: `./app.component.html`,
  styleUrls: [`./app.component.css`]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  signUpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private emailService: EmailService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      email: ["", [Validators.required], [this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)]]
    });
  }

  //Validator for checking if email name is taken or not
  validateEmailNotTaken(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> {
    if (control.value === null || control.value.length === 0) {
      return of(null);
    } else {
      return timer(1000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          // RIGHT HERE 
          return this.emailService.checkEmailExists(control.value).pipe(
            map(res => {
              //Do what with response
              console.log(res);
              if (res) {
                return of(null);
              }
              return { taken: true };
            })
          );
        })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Code Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-custom-validator?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: The binding was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your validateEmailNotTaken method is not getting an instance of the component. You'll need to bind this when creating formGroup. Modify your code like this:-

```
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required], [this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)]]
});
```

Please try this and let me know.